# Copy (row) from 2D array to 1D array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

So I have a 2d array multiarray[a][b] and another array buf[b].

I'm having trouble assigning 'buf' to be equal to one of the rows of the multiarray. What is the exact syntax to do this?

Comment: What code do you have right now?

Comment: You can't assign arrays. Array names are not lvalues.

Comment: buf[0] = &multiarray[index]; is what I have.

@Chris, but arrays are treated like pointers in C, yes?

Comment: Arrays are not pointers, either. They decay in some cases, but this is not one of them.

Comment: Upvoted because a -1 didn't seem justified. I detest drive-by downvoting.

Comment: @JamesPoulson: That's not a valid reason for up-voting.  You should up-vote because you believe *"This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear"*, not in order to counteract someone else's down-vote.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Perhaps. But there are a lot of shoulds in this world that can become should nots. To give an example the Greeks "should" apply austerity measures to the point where people are jumping to their death from the Acropolis. The user is new, he is responsive and really should be given the opportunity to clarify his question. At least that's my pov.

Comment: @JamesPoulson That downvote was probably collected because this question made it onto at least one quality review queue, where actions like voting and/or editing and/or flagging need to take place to effect an action.

Comment: My upvote remains. Feel free to correct if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

```
// a 2-D array of char
char multiarray[2][5] = { 0 };
// a 1-D array of char, with matching dimension
char buf[5];
// set the contents of buf equal to the contents of the first row of multiarray.
memcpy(buf, multiarray[0], sizeof(buf));
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are not assignable. There is no core language syntax for this. Array copying in C++ is implemented at library level or at user code level.

If this is supposed to be C++ and if you really need to create a separate *copy* `buf` of some row `i` of the 2D array `mutiarray`, then you can use `std::copy`

```
#include <algorithm>
...

SomeType multiarray[a][b], buf[b];
...
std::copy(multiarray[i], multiarray[i] + b, buf);
```

or in C++11

```
std::copy_n(multiarray[i], b, buf);
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the code has similar function in snort (old version), it is borrowed from tcpdump, maybe helpful to you.

```
/****************************************************************************
 *
 * Function: copy_argv(u_char **)
 *
 * Purpose: Copies a 2D array (like argv) into a flat string.  Stolen from
 *          TCPDump.
 *
 * Arguments: argv => 2D array to flatten
 *
 * Returns: Pointer to the flat string
 *
 ****************************************************************************/
char *copy_argv(char **argv)
{
  char **p;
  u_int len = 0;
  char *buf;
  char *src, *dst;
  void ftlerr(char *, ...);

  p = argv;
  if (*p == 0) return 0;

  while (*p)
    len += strlen(*p++) + 1;

  buf = (char *) malloc (len);
  if(buf == NULL)
  {
     fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
     exit(0);
  }
  p = argv;
  dst = buf;
  while ((src = *p++) != NULL)
  {
      while ((*dst++ = *src++) != '\0');
      dst[-1] = ' ';
  }
  dst[-1] = '\0';

  return buf;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vectors:

```
vector<vector<int> > int2D;
vector<int> int1D;
```

You could simply use the vector's built in assignment operator:

```
int1D = int2D[A];//Will copy the array at index 'A'
```

If you're using c-style arrays, a primitive approach would be to copy each element from the selected row to the single dimensional array:

Example:

```
//Assuming int2D is a 2-Dimensional array of size greater than 2.
//Assuming int1D is a 1-Dimensional array of size equal to or greater than a row in int2D.

int a = 2;//Assuming row 2 was the selected row to be copied.

for(unsigned int b = 0; b < sizeof(int2D[a])/sizeof(int); ++b){
    int1D[b] = int2D[a][b];//Will copy a single integer value.
}
```

Syntax is a rule, algorithm is what you probably meant/desired.