# Passing A Two Dimensional Array Into A Function That Only Takes A One Dimensional Array (C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks

I'm learning vertex array objects in OpenGL. Running codeblocks with mingw gcc as my compiler. I loaded data from a text file using this (just a bunch of quads to be used as walls)

```
void setup_world()                                                          // Sets up the world using the world.txt file
{
    float x, y, z, u, v;
    FILE *filein;
    char oneline[255];
    filein = fopen("Data/world.txt", "rt");
    readstr(filein, oneline);
    sscanf(oneline, "NUMPOLLIES %d\n", &numpolygons);
    int cols = 13;
    int rows = numpolygons+1;
    polygondata = new float*[rows];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        polygondata[i] = new float[cols];
    polygondata[0][0] = 69.01;
    for (int loop = 0; loop < numpolygons; loop++)
    {
        readstr(filein, oneline);
        sscanf(oneline, "%f %f %f %f %f %f", &x, &y, &z, &u, &v);
        polygondata[loop][0] = x;
        polygondata[loop][1] = y;
        polygondata[loop][2] = z;
        readstr(filein, oneline);
        sscanf(oneline, "%f %f %f %f %f %f", &x, &y, &z, &u, &v);
        polygondata[loop][3] = x;
        polygondata[loop][4] = y;
        polygondata[loop][5] = z;
        readstr(filein, oneline);
        sscanf(oneline, "%f %f %f %f %f %f", &x, &y, &z, &u, &v);
        polygondata[loop][6] = x;
        polygondata[loop][7] = y;
        polygondata[loop][8] = z;
        readstr(filein, oneline);
        sscanf(oneline, "%f %f %f %f %f %f", &x, &y, &z, &u, &v);
        polygondata[loop][9] = x;
        polygondata[loop][10] = y;
        polygondata[loop][11] = z;
    }
    fclose(filein);
    return;
}
```

I know it's kind of redundant but it will do until I get around to rewriting the part that stores all the data into the array. 
Typically, data is passed to OpenGL for vertex array objects using

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

OpenGL would usually take in an array similar to this, generating a quad

```
float g_vertex_buffer_data[] =
{
    -1.0, -1.0,-5.0,
    1.0, -1.0, -5.0,
    1.0,  1.0, -5.0,
    -1.0,  1.0, -5.0,
};
```

The function expects g_vertex_buffer_data to be a one-dimensional arrary, however i stored all my vertex data into a two dimensional array, the first dimension used for storage of several polygons (in this case QUADS) and the second dimension is used to store all 12 vertexs of for a quad.

What would be the best way to approach this?

 A proposed solution that i came up with was creating another array (single dimension, however) that would temporarly store the vertex data from one polygon at a time. Directly after I would pass this single dimension array to the glBufferData function (since glBufferData has no problem receiving single dimension arrays). I would repeat this for every polygon effectively traversing my entire two dimensional array and passing the to the function data into glBufferData polygon by polygon. I know im going to have to put each polygon in a seperate vertex buffer no need to remind me. I just need to know if it's possible to pass in one part of my two dimensional array!

 Is there an easier and more efficient way to go about doing this.

Comment: You can pass 1 row of the 2D array with giving one of the indices

Comment: I'm confused as to how you label this C++ when you don't actually use any C++. Except maybe the ability to define variables anywhere, but even that's legal C99. And I'm not talking about your choice of file IO APIs.

Comment: glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof (polygondata[0]), polygondata[0] , GL_STATIC_DRAW); <- like that?

Comment: @Gishump yes looks like that should work, have you tried?

Comment: @NicolBolas go easy on him, he is a new user, besides, it is legal C++ as well, and the rest of the code could very well be using a lot of C++ specific code

Comment: Thank you! i tried it that exact way before and i thought it wasn't working but it actually did haha.

Comment: @KarthikT: A "new" C++ programmer shouldn't be using `new` nearly so often. The code is more like C than C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a much better idea that doesn't involve... what you did.

```
std::vector<GLfloat> polygondata;
polygondata.reserve(numpolygons * 4 * 3);
for (int loop = 0; loop < numpolygons * 4 * 3; loop++)
{
    readstr(filein, oneline);
    sscanf(oneline, "%f %f %f %f %f %f", &x, &y, &z, &u, &v);
    polygondata.push_back(x);
    polygondata.push_back(y);
    polygondata.push_back(z);
}
```

Not only are pointless memory allocations removed, you now have your data in a 1D array, which you can index in a 1D fashion. If you want to access vertex X of polygon Y, you use `Y * numpolygons + X` for the index. And you can upload the data to OpenGL using a simple `glBufferData(..., sizeof(GLfloat) * polygondata.size(), &polygondata[0], ...)` command.

Comment: explain how i would use the polygondata vector in glBufferData();

Comment: sorry i can't become an expert overnight

Comment: @Gishump: "*explain how i would use the polygondata vector in glBufferData();*" I did. It's right there in the answer.

Comment: @Gishump: But you can read (I think so). And insulting other people isn't very nice. Nicol Bolas did should exactly what you should to. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/opengl/topusers so see which people clould actually help you. Congratulations, you just directly insulted one of the top 3.

Comment: Yeah, i just feel like he was trying to make me look like an idiot up in the question comments. thanks for all the help everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can pass just 1 row of your 2D array with giving one of two indices, It will then refer to just that particular polygons data.

You can see similar usage at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13427008/1520364